# How to handle customize button event in data grid view according to the another column value in data grid view

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a program for retrieving data from the database to the data grid view programmatically. It is working fine. Then I have added button column to the data grid view and have written button handle event for that. the button is shown in the grid view but when I click it nothing happen anything.

Data Grid Veiw

[image]

Below is my source code:

```
private void TesterHome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source= LAPTOP-J70EHC58 ; Initial Catalog= Defect_Management_system ; Integrated Security = True ; Connect Timeout = 30 ; ");
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            string sqlstmt = "SELECT * FROM defect";
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlstmt, con);
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
                con.Close();
                dgvTester.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error + "Invalid");
            }

            DataGridViewButtonColumn dgvbtnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            dgvTester.Columns.Add(dgvbtnColumn);
            dgvbtnColumn.HeaderText = "";
            dgvbtnColumn.Text = "View";
            dgvbtnColumn.Name = "dgvBtn";
            dgvbtnColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        }

        private void dgvTester_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

            if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                QA review form qa = new QA review form();
                qa.show();
            }
        }
```

This table has a status column. I want to customize the button according to the status.

ex.

- If Status is **new** then click the view button open a **new defect
  form**.
- If Status is **open** then click the view button open a **QA review
  form**.
- If Status is **assigned** then click the view button open a
  d**eveloper review form**.
- If Status is **duplicate**, **postponed**, and **deferred** then
  click the view button open a **reopen form**.

Comment: try to use this if condition in your `CellContentClick` event => `if (senderGrid[e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewButtonCell)`

Comment: It also not working. same issue when click the button nothing happens

Comment: check once if you click on view button then CellContentclick event is fore or not?

Comment: how can I check it? I can't understand

Comment: add breakpoint in CellContentclick and then click view button and check if debugger comes to that breakpoint or not

Comment: No its not coming. it is only comes to **dgvbtnColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true; **line.

Comment: what is wrong with my code

Comment: why CellContentClick event not working

Comment: I would suggest you to recreate an event handler and delete existing event hadler